# Foreign key and the primary key in the same table

Tags: mysql

I need to create a relationship between two attributes in the same table. So both primary key and the foreign keys are in the same table. Here I have a table called User_Type. Primary key is User_ID. It should be the foreign key of Parent_ID.

Ex:

```
User_Type 
User_ID
User_Name
Parent_ID
User_Type_Division
```

But when I'm creating the relationship I get an error like this.

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`mydb`.`user_type`, CONSTRAINT `Parent_User_Type` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`Parent_ID`) REFERENCES `user_type` (`User_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)").

Is there any way available to avoid this error. Please someone let me know.

And Here I have given the Query of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_type` (
  `User_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `User_Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Parent_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `User_Type_Division` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `User_ID_Format` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data_Entered_Person` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Entered_Time` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`User_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `User_Name_UNIQUE` (`User_Name`),
  KEY `ParentUserType` (`Parent_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Comment: Remove the foreign key constraint on parent_id and check issue is solved ?

Comment: Thanks Suleman for replying. How can I do that. And doesn't it affect the future results of the table.

Comment: would you append your query with the question ?

Comment: Can you post your query how you are creating relation along with table structure?

Comment: Can you tell me if the table is having existing data?

Comment: Ya I edited the question and included the query. Table has only the data related to the maintenance staff. I entered them to the table directly not using the application I created

Comment: I think you should clear the data before creating key, it might be that there is a data that does  not justify relation ship. please create a test table and check that.Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that the `User_ID` column and the `Parent_ID` column are of the same datatype.

Also, your `User_ID` key column is set to NOT NULL, but your `Parent_ID` column is set to null.  that could be the problem.  Set `Parent_ID` to NOT NULL and then try creating the FK relationship again.  This is one of the options I was talking about.  However, if you already have data in your table, this could be an issue too.

Comment: Hello Sly Thanks for replying. Yep. They are same types.

Comment: Including attributes like unsigned, etc?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I think is the solution now that I have seen your CREATE statement.

Comment: I did the same. But still the same issue is coming.

Comment: Double check that they are the same datatype, length, default value, null/not null setting, everything.

Comment: Use_ID is Auto Incrementing and Parent_ID Not. Will it be an issue?

Comment: Assuming you've set the columns to be `NOT NULL`, that won't be an issue.  `Parent_ID` can't be null because no null value will exist for `User_ID`.  The purpose of the foreign key relationship is to ensure there is an associated value from wherever it has an established a relationship.  For your setup, that means that the values of the two columns have to match.  So if you have already populated the table with data and there are null values in the `Parent_ID` column, you will have to fix those null records first to match with a `User_ID` record before you can establish the FK relationship.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to add and enforce `foreign key` on existing data.

***Step 1***: You need to stop foreign key checks for the *current session*.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

***Step 2***: Add `foreign key` to your table.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_name FOREIGN KEY ( columnName ) REFERENCES ...
```

***Step 3***: Enable foreign key checks.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

***Working Example***:

```
mysql> create table fkchk( i int not null primary key auto_increment, n int );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.26 sec)

mysql> insert into fkchk(n) values ( 0 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%fore%';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| foreign_key_checks | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table fkchk
     > add constraint fk_n foreign key (n) references fkchk(i)
     > on delete no action;
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row:
      a foreign key constraint fails
      (`test`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-6fc_14'>,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_n` FOREIGN KEY (`n`)
      REFERENCES `fkchk` (`i`) ON DELETE NO ACTION)

mysql> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%fore%';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| foreign_key_checks | OFF   |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table fkchk
     > add constraint fk_n foreign key (n) references fkchk(i)
     > on delete no action;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.50 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into fkchk(n) values ( 0 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.32 sec)

mysql> select * from fkchk;
+---+------+
| i | n    |
+---+------+
| 1 |    0 |
| 2 |    0 |
+---+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%fore%';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| foreign_key_checks | ON   |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into fkchk(n) values ( 1 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> insert into fkchk(n) values ( 0 );
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row:
      a foreign key constraint fails
      (`test`.`fkchk`,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_n` FOREIGN KEY (`n`)
      REFERENCES `fkchk` (`i`) ON DELETE NO ACTION)
mysql>
mysql> select * from fkchk;
+---+------+
| i | n    |
+---+------+
| 1 |    0 |
| 2 |    0 |
| 3 |    1 |
+---+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```